# Login with AD to FreePBX

Tags: authentication, active-directory, voip, freepbx

Good day,
I've a server with FreePBX.
I've successfully configured it to make calls from softphones and IP phones.

Now I want to use AD users in FreePBX, so I assigned them an extension, and connected the AD to FreePBX, so I can see them there, however, I cannot manage to configure them on the phones.

I've tried to configure a softphone (MicroSIP, phonerlite, jitsi, ... ) but no luck so far.
It says wrong password but when managing the users I don't see how to assign a password so I assume the password is the one in Active directory, which is the one being used and throwing the error.

Any idea of how to solve this?
Thank you in advance!